# How to remove latches in code of 1-bit ALU?

Tags: verilog

I am trying to build a 32-bit ALU in Verilog. I've implemented a 1-bit ALU at the beginning.
The ALU should have only 4 functions, not all of them: add, sub, and, or. This is my code:

```
module ALU(
    input wire [3:0] OPCode,
    input wire  Operand1,
    input wire  Operand2,
    input wire cin,
    output reg Result,
    output reg Cout
    );

always@(*)
    begin
      case(OPCode)
           4'b0000: Result = Operand1&Operand2;
           4'b0001: Result = Operand1|Operand2;
           4'b0010:
           begin
                Result = cin ^(Operand1 ^ (Operand2 ^ cin));
                Cout = ((Operand2 ^ cin) & Operand1) | ((Operand1 ^ (Operand2 ^ cin)) & cin);
           end
                4'b0110:
                begin
                    Result = cin ^(Operand1 ^ (Operand2 ^ cin));
                    Cout = ((Operand2 ^ cin) & Operand1) | ((Operand1 ^ (Operand2 ^ cin)) & cin);
                end
       endcase    
    end    
endmodule
```

The problem here is that it generates unnecessary LATCH gates. I already know it's because I'm not covering all cases in my `case` statement; however, these are the only cases that I have.
What should I do to fix my `case` statement?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the top of the `always` block, but before the `case` statement, set initial values to all the signals being assigned in the `always` block.  In your code, this means:

```
      Result = 0;
      Cout = 0;
```

Since combinational logic uses blocking assignments, the initial values will be properly overwritten when one of your 4 opcodes is selected.  Here is the full `always` block:

```
always@(*)
    begin
      Result = 0;
      Cout = 0;
      case(OPCode)
           4'b0000: Result = Operand1&Operand2;
           4'b0001: Result = Operand1|Operand2;
           4'b0010:
           begin
                Result = cin ^(Operand1 ^ (Operand2 ^ cin));
                Cout = ((Operand2 ^ cin) & Operand1) | ((Operand1 ^ (Operand2 ^ cin)) & cin);
           end
           4'b0110:
           begin
               Result = cin ^(Operand1 ^ (Operand2 ^ cin));
               Cout = ((Operand2 ^ cin) & Operand1) | ((Operand1 ^ (Operand2 ^ cin)) & cin);
           end
       endcase    
    end
```

There are other ways to do this as well, but this is a common approach.

Answer (score -1):

The issue is that you coded a latch in your logic. Consider the following:

```
aways @*
   if(en)
      a <= b;
```

In the above scheme, if `en` is high, then `a` changes as soon as `b` changes. But, if `en` is low, `a` will keep its old value even if `b` changes. This is a *latch* behavior and synthesis tools recognize the specific pattern in order to generate latches.

Algorithmically, a latch is derived from a not fully-specified conditional statement, like the above `if` without `else`, where `a` is not driven in some cases.

To express a combinatorial logic, you need to make sure that `a` is driven in all cases. The following shows a simple combinatorial two-way mux

```
always @*
   if (en)
      a = b;
   else
      a = c;
```

In the above `a` is driven in all branches of the *if* statement. BTW, use of `=` or `<=` does not define the type or the coded device. However, `<=` is recommended for sequential logic, like latches and `=` should be used for combinatorial devices.

The other way to make sure that `a` is always driven is to assign a certain value to it before the conditional statement, like here:

```
always @* begin
   a = c;
   if (en)
      a = b;
end
```

This is a well recognized design pattern which works with all synthesis tools.

So, your code is similar to the above, and you do not drive *Result* and *Count* in all branches of the case statement. In other words you are missing `default:`. You can add it as

```
always @*
  case ...
   default: begin
     Result = 0;
     Cout = 0;
   end
 endcase
 ...
```

Or you can use the second scheme with initialization upfront and assign them before the case statement, as in *toolic's* answer.